# upload file with post params

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, request, http-post

I want send file to url with some post params like "chat_id", "caption" and file must be sended as 'photo' field-name.
but I found only methods to send only POST params without file or sending only file without POST params and custom file name param..
This code send only `params` field, but I need also `files` field.

```
from urllib import parse, request
...
files={'photo': open('file.jpg','rb')}          
params = parse.urlencode({'chat_id': chat_id, 'caption': 'test'})
#headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"}      

req = request.Request(url, params.encode('ascii'))
response = request.urlopen(req)
print(response.read())
```

Python 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. I found solution.
I install external lib [Requests: HTTP for Humans](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests).
and now i'm using `requests`

```
import requests
...
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+self.token+'/sendPhoto' #'/sendmessage'
print('request to '+url+' with params '+chat_id+' ' + text)     

headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

files = {'photo': open('file.jpg', 'rb')}
params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'caption': text}
r = requests.post(url,  files=files, params=params)     
print(r.text)
```